# Better way to read last portion of URL

Tags: php, string, url, search, url-parsing

This script should detect the last portion in the full path, and if it is `stackoverflow` output `ok`

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$current_url_arr = explode('/',$current_url);
$count = count($current_url_arr);

if($current_url_arr[$count-2] == 'stackoverflow'){
    echo 'ok';
}
else {
    echo 'not ok';
}
```

---

Example 1: `www.myserver.ext/something/else/stackoverflow/`
Output: `ok`

---

Example 2: `www.myserver.ext/something/else/stackoverflow`
Output: `not ok`

---

Example 3: `www.myserver.ext/something/else/stackoverflow/foo`
Output: `not ok`

---

I hope that you understand the idea. This script works fine, but I'm wondering if there is any better, elegant way to read last portion of URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! There's `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    $info = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));

    if($info[count($info) - 1] === 'stackoverflow') {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'not ok';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (preg_match("#stackoverflow/$#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {

    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: It will echo `ok` also in case of `.../foobarstackoverflow/`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be the best way:

```
<?php

    $url = "www.myserver.ext/something/else/stackoverflow/";

    $fullpath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $paths = explode("/", $fullpath);
    $path = $paths[sizeof($paths)-1];

    if ($path === "stackoverflow") {
        # Condition satisfied
    }

?>
```

Comment: It only works in case an url that ends with `/stackoverflow`. It does not work with your example url. See my answer for clarification.

Comment: @Struna if you add `$paths = explode("/", $fullpath, (sizeof($paths)-2));` after the first explode, that should prevent the last "/" from being taken off the string, so you'll get the last folder name + "/" only.

Answer (score 1):

I think use of `basename()` is a better idea than `explode()`. `basename()` function will return last portion of url whether there is trailing slashes or not.

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(basename($uri) == 'stackoverflow') {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'not ok';
}
?>
```

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that if trailing characters in the input string will match the delimiter (boundary) string, `explode()` will produce en array with last item being an empty string. Thus your Example 3 will output `ok`.

`www.myserver.ext/something/else/stackoverflow/foo/` will output `not ok`.

The shortest way to achieve your need is:

```
if (preg_match("#/stackoverflow/$#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

This will echo `ok` only if the url ends with `/stackoverflow/`.